How to prevent a React component from freezing the page after loading?
I am using the following library uiwjs/react-json-view, it is the typical library to view json. The issue is that I want it to load a large json. But when it does, it freezes the page in the process. I have already used Suspense and Lazy from react, to load the component, and it does its job. The thing is that it seems that after the component appears, it starts processing the json, causing the page to freeze. Does anyone know what I could do?
My goal is to be able to view a large json without the page freezing in the process.

JavaScript is a single-threaded programming language. JavaScript runs in the main thread. When your component is rendered it starts computing and it seems in your case this JSON viewer is computing in a non optimal way.
To the question "Does anyone know what I could do?" I can suggest you use another library or write the JSON viewer yourself, because uiwjs/react-json-view is obviously written in a non optimal way for large data.
Another posibility would be you are using it in a wrong way.

I have used other json viewer type libraries.  but they have many functions, but nothing optimal for rendering long json, maybe there is a way.  but they do not express it in their promotion, they do not even see it as a possibility.  I have chosen to make my own, but it is a shame that such good bookstores fail in that.

Computations with very long strings are slow. Even JSON.parse and JSON.stringify are taking some time to compute large data. Let alone additional functionality on top of it. Even if you manage to build the library yourself, you can't ensure the user will have good hardware to compute the same way as with yours. Is it really that crucial to load this JSON so fast? How would the user benefit from it since it's a very large data anyway?

Hi everyone, I finally created my own JSONViewer from scratch. There was no other option. I will soon share my project, which I am sure will be useful to many. Thanks for the help.

Hello, I am interested in seeing your solution. It's not very trivial thing. Handling large data in the browser is a hassle.
